# Define fallback font in xterm

Tags: fonts, xterm, monospace

I use `Ubuntu Mono` font in xterm terminal and, to my regret, there are no glyphs for some useful unicode characters such as scissors (2702) or some superscript and subscript symbols. Fortunately, `Monospace` has these glyphs. Is there an opportunity to configure fallback font(s) to catch missing glyphs in xterm? If not, can I merge `Ubuntu Mono` and `Monospace` to one font? Nowadays, I have next configuration.

```
XTerm*faceName: Ubuntu Mono
XTerm*faceSize: 12
```

It seems separating `faceName` value with comma does not work.

Comment: Possibly this: [command-line-tool-for-merging-fonts-files](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13380/command-line-tool-for-merging-fonts-files).

Comment: As far as I can figure out, it's not possible to define a fallback font for xterm. You could use another terminal emulator or use a trick such as the one suggested by Thomas Dickey to create a new font file with all the glyphs you need.

Comment: You are right. Xterm, unfortunately, unlike gnome-terminal, does not use any other fonts for missing glyphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since patch [#338](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_338) in late 2018, xterm supports TrueType fallback fonts.  No change was needed to user's configuration.

Comment: Though I do not use xterm anymore, anyway thank you.